# Find all semicolons surrounded by numbers in MS Office WORD

Tags: regex, windows, word-2016

In a word document, I'd like to find all semicolons that are surrounded by numbers. so I need the Find/Replace DialogBox to find and select `;` in `123;4` and `1;234` (but not `example;example` or not `example; example`) .
Please note that in the example above, I just need the semicolon selected for formatting.
I know the basics of RegEx but WORD's so called Wildcards are different. All I could do so far was to find the whole string (eg `123;4`) using `([0-9]{1,};[0-9]{1,})` but like I said I only need `;` so that I change it's font size, color etc.
Please help. I don't like to spend the whole day on a stupid document.

Comment: Try `([0-9]{1,});([0-9]{1,})` and replace with `\1\2` (if you need to remove the `;`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the reply but I don't want to remove `;`. I need a regex to find & select `;`. I don't want to move/remove anything. I think word is not able to do that.

Comment: It is not possible. But you may try something like `>;<`. Although it will also select `;` in some other contexts (like `example;example`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. oh man, it's gonna be a long day :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around Microsoft Word's limitations by inserting a custom sequence of characters to mark the instances of `;` that you want to format, and then deleting the custom sequence of characters. In this example I will use the character sequence `zzzzz` as this likely doesn't appear anywhere else in your document.

## The Process

First do a find-and-replace:

Find what: `([0-9]{1,});([0-9]{1,})`

Replace with: `\1zzzzz;\2`

Now you can select all instances of `zzzzz;` and apply the desired format.

Lastly, do another find-and-replace:

Find what: `zzzzz`

Replace with: nothing

Comment: yes! exactly what I wanted. your workaround did the tedius job in a matter of seconds! thanks.